# How to ensure that data remains consistent and up-to-date when working with two Fragments in an Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

In my app's landscape, I have two fragments layout: one is inside a ViewPager and contains a RecyclerView, and the other fragment contains a form for adding items to the RecyclerView.

However, when I try to add a new item to the RecyclerView using the form in the second fragment, the RecyclerView in the first fragment is not updated in real-time. Instead, the RecyclerView is only updated when I restart the app.

I'm wondering if Is there a way to solve this problem and ensure that the RecyclerView updates in real-time when a new item is added from the second fragment?
as you see in the picture below!
[image]

**Update:**

I have fixed the problem by using viewmodel between these 2 fragments. If someone has the same problem just use viewmodel. :)

Comment: call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter of the recyclerview on left

Answer (score 0):

one thing you can do is call

```
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

or else you can go for combination of ListAdapter and DiffUtil so no more calling notifyDataSetChanged and it is very easy to implement

Thank you